# expose tcp service (port 5432) on specific subdomain via ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, tcp, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster that exposes Postgresql on port 5432 via [this information](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md), this works like a charm. I'm currently testing this on my machine, and it works on `db.x.io` (`x` being my domain). But it also works on `localhost`. This seems fair, as it only creates a binding upon port 5432 to my service.

How can i also filter on subdomain? So its only accessible via `db.x.io`

Comment: Hi Is there any document which could help how to apply the configurations mentioned in this doc?.  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

Comment: the document itself should be enough? Maybe make a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much that `TCP` protocol has in terms of filtering. This is because `TCP` protocol uses only `IP:Port` combination, no headers like in HTTP. Your subdomain is resolved by `DNS` to `IP` address before connection is made.

According to [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/) documentation you can do the following:

> - [Restricting Access by IP Address](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/#restrict)
> - [Limiting the Number of TCP Connections](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/#limit_conn)
> - [Limiting the Bandwidth](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/#limit_bandwidth)

---

You can try to limit access from localhost by adding `deny 127.0.0.1` to nginx configuration, however it will most likely break the Postgresql instead. So it is a risky suggestion.

For kubernetes ingress object it would be:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
      deny 127.0.0.1;
```

Based on [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/custom-annotations/) documentation.

Comment: I mostly want to limit by access of domain, only to match on a specific subdomain. So not necessarily.on IP. Didnt even think of adding the config via nginx conf..